# Floating div top spacing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to align the red columns under the black columns without changing the HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/3HUNz/28/

Are there any jquery or css solutions for this?

CSS:

```
.col{
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding:2px;
    float:left;
}

.clear{clear:both;}

.col1{height: 200px;}
.col2{height: 300px;}
.col3{height: 200px;}
.col4{height: 200px; border: 1px solid red;}
.col5{height: 220px; border: 1px solid red;}
.col6{height: 120px; border: 1px solid red;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col col1">1</div>
<div class="col col2">2</div>
<div class="col col3">3</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="col col4">4</div>
<div class="col col5">5</div>
<div class="col col6">6</div>
```

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @lilalinux, you can just specify [What have you tried ?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Its quite handy domain.

Comment: @frank, please add associated code, as jsfiddle is a not a permanent code holder

Answer (score 1):

use float property

```
.col2 {
float: right;
height: 200px;
}
```

and set

```
.col3{border: 1px solid red;
float: left;
}
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3HUNz/17/)

Comment: Thx for the response. I now realize that my example was horrible; I have made a new one; http://jsfiddle.net/3HUNz/28/ Is there a way to  dynamicly align 4 5 6 to the bottom of column 1 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

As you have fixed height for first div, you can place the red div easily below the first div by using position:absolute

```
.col3{border: 1px solid red; position:absolute; top:100px}​
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/3HUNz/18/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the float concept to get them in line:

http://jsfiddle.net/3HUNz/16/

Answer (score 0):

If the boxes are staying the same then you could do:

```
.col3 { margin-top: -90px; }​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X37eZ/